# Colored output from node stdout when redirected

Tags: node.js, terminal, colors, systemd, ansi-escape

I'm using 'colors' module with node js. When I run it simply with 'node app.js' I can see colored output in terminal.

However, when I redirect the output with 'node app.js > out.log &' or when I'm running it as a systemd daemon and looking on output with journalctl, colors are gone.

I want to be able to run node program as systemd daemon while being able to preserve colors in the log output. Please help me to understand the problem and find the solution if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you see the output without colors because by default journalctl uses `short` as a output mode, if you use `cat`, you'll see your colors

example:

`journalctl -o cat -u myservice.service`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried this and it didn't help. Output is still colorless.

Comment: ok so the issue is that colors library is not printing the values with color when run on systemd, not that systemd cant print them... you can check try executing your app with --color=always and you'll see colors (just tested it with `node /path/to/index.js --color=always`), if you cant afford a extra cli, set the environmental variable `COLORTERM` in your service file. (you still need to use -o cat on journalctl)

Comment: --color=always did the trick, though it's strange that it's not mentioned in 'man node', thanks!

Comment: oh is not a node thing, is a `colors` things https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/lib/system/supports-colors.js#L34-L38

glad it worked

Comment: Oh, then it's strange that it's not mentioned in 'colors' README on a github page.